# comparing object to another object which extends the first one

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am trying to compare two lists of objects when they are mix up. I have a class `Sms` and another class `ArchivedSms extends Sms`.

How to compare List of these objects using `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)` ?

```
List<Sms> smses = new ArrayList<Sms>();
List<ArchivedSms> archivedSmses = new ArrayList<ArchivedSms>();

smses.addAll(archivedSmses);
```

How to compare these objects assume they have both same fields, so I would like to compare for example phoneNumbers which are strings.

Comment: Implement a `Comparator<Sms>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write your own comparator that implements `Comparator<Sms>`

```
public class SmsComparator implements `Comparator<Sms>` {
    @Override
    public bool compare(Sms o1, Sms o2) {
       // Implement comparison logic
    }
 }
```

Let's assume each `Sms` instance has a field `int a` so the comparator would look something like this:

```
public class SmsComparator implements `Comparator<Sms>` {
    @Override
    public bool compare(Sms o1, Sms o2) {
       if(o1.getA() > o2.getA()) return 1;
       else if(o1.getA() > o2.getA()) return -1;
       else return 0;
    }
 }
```

You can do the same inline when calling `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(smes, new Comparator<Sms>() {
   @Override
    public bool compare(Sms o1, Sms o2) {
       if(o1.getA() > o2.getA()) return 1;
       else if(o1.getA() > o2.getA()) return -1;
       else return 0;
    }
})
```

And in java 8 you can do the same as a lambda function (because that's a functional interface).

Comment: can't I user inline new Comparator  ? for example Collections.sort(smses, new Comparator<Sms>(){});

Comment: Sure, just implement the `compare` method inline. In java 8 this can also be a lambda expression because that's a functional interface.

Comment: I wrote  @Override
 public int compare(Sms o1, Sms o2) {

  if (o1.getPhoneNumber().equals(o2.getPhoneNumber())) {
   return 1;
  } else if (!(o1.getPhoneNumber().equals(o2.getPhoneNumber()))) {
   return -1;
  } else
   return 0;
 }

but it still not working @Collections.sort(smses, new SmsComparator());

is it okey to compare here Sms and ArchivedSms class ?